# Is there any plan for a ROS2 distro compatible with C++20?

Tags: c++20, ros2

ROS2 `humble` distro currently supports C++17. Can it support C++20 modules?

Is there any prospect for a future ROS2 distro to support, be compatible with C++20, or leverage C++20 features?

1. Is there any plan for a future ROS2 distro that compiles with C++20
2. One that utilises C++20 features (especially C++20 modules)

How far are we from supporting C++20 modules? Will "modules" ever be supported, or are they in conflict with how ROS2 is designed?

Comment: This question is probably better asked on the ROS forums.

Comment: As far as roadmap and projects direction, you probably should post on https://discourse.ros.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, you can build your own packages with C++20, and link them to ROS 2 packages build with C++17 just fine.

Be aware though: not all C++20 features are supported on all compilers. Of note: as of writing, C++20 Modules are only *partially* supported on GCC, Clang, and MSVC, so I would guess a full migration of the ROS core to C++20 modules is a long way off. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support for a more detailed summary.

As far as ROS2 design, plans, and direction, you should probably post on https://discourse.ros.org/